# Laravel Error RouteCollection.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i'm getting the error below when i migrated a project from one computer to another:

i imported the mysql table, did a migrate and when i click on the links i get a route error:

NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

My routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' =>[ 'web']], function () {
   Route::any('user/login', ['as' => 'user.login', 'uses' => 'UserController@login']);
   Route::any('user/dologin', ['as' => 'user.dologin', 'uses' => 'UserController@dologin']);
});

 Route::group(['middleware' =>[ 'web','auth']], function () {
//Route::any('/', function () { return view('user.dashboard'); });
Route::any('user/dashboard', ['as' => 'user.dashboard', 'uses' => 'UserController@dashboard']);
Route::any('user/logout', ['as' => 'user.logout' , 'uses' => 'UserController@logout']);

Route::any('sos/create', ['as' => 'sos.create', 'uses' => 'SosController@create']);
Route::any('sos/index', ['as' => 'sos.index' , 'uses' => 'SosController@index']);
Route::any('sos/store', ['as' => 'sos.store' , 'uses' => 'SosController@store']);
Route::any('sos/show/{id}', ['as' => 'sos.show' , 'uses' => 'SosController@show']);
Route::any('sos/edit/{id}', ['as' => 'sos.edit' , 'uses' => 'SosController@edit']);
Route::any('sos/update/{id}', ['as' => 'sos.update' , 'uses' => 'SosController@update']);
Route::any('sos/destroy/{id}', ['as' => 'sos.destroy' , 'uses' => 'SosController@destroy']);
Route::any('sos/submit/{id}', ['as' => 'sos.submit' , 'uses' => 'SosController@submit']);
Route::any('sos/approve/{id}', ['as' => 'sos.approve' , 'uses' => 'SosController@approve']);
Route::any('sos/reject/{id}', ['as' => 'sos.reject' , 'uses' => 'SosController@reject']);
Route::any('sos/customer-search', ['as'=>'sos.customer-search','uses'=>'SosController@search']);
Route::any('sos/customer-selected', ['as'=>'sos.customer-selected','uses'=>'SosController@customerSelected']);

Route::any('order/create', ['as' => 'order.create', 'uses' => 'OrderController@create']);
Route::any('order/index', ['as' => 'order.index' , 'uses' => 'OrderController@index']);
Route::any('order/store', ['as' => 'order.store' , 'uses' => 'OrderController@store']);
Route::any('order/show/{id}', ['as' => 'order.show' , 'uses' => 'OrderController@show']);
Route::any('order/edit/{id}', ['as' => 'order.edit' , 'uses' => 'OrderController@edit']);
Route::any('order/update/{id}', ['as' => 'order.update' , 'uses' => 'OrderController@update']);
Route::any('order/destroy/{id}', ['as' => 'order.destroy' , 'uses' => 'OrderController@destroy']);
Route::any('order/submit/{id}', ['as' => 'order.submit' , 'uses' => 'OrderController@submit']);
Route::any('order/approve/{id}', ['as' => 'order.approve' , 'uses' => 'OrderController@approve']);
Route::any('order/reject/{id}', ['as' => 'order.reject' , 'uses' => 'OrderController@reject']);
Route::any('order/customer-search', ['as'=>'order.customer-search','uses'=>'OrderController@search']);
Route::any('order/customer-selected', ['as'=>'order.customer-selected','uses'=>'OrderController@customerSelected']);
Route::any('order/ship_to_address_area', ['as'=>'order.ship_to_address_area','uses'=>'OrderController@ship_to_address_area']);
Route::any('order/dept_name_field', ['as'=>'order.dept_name_field','uses'=>'OrderController@dept_name_field']);

Route::any('equipment/create', ['as' => 'equipment.create', 'uses' => 'EquipmentController@create']);
Route::any('equipment/index', ['as' => 'equipment.index' , 'uses' => 'EquipmentController@index']);
Route::any('equipment/store', ['as' => 'equipment.store' , 'uses' => 'EquipmentController@store']);
Route::any('equipment/show/{id}', ['as' => 'equipment.show' , 'uses' => 'EquipmentController@show']);
Route::any('equipment/edit/{id}', ['as' => 'equipment.edit' , 'uses' => 'EquipmentController@edit']);
Route::any('equipment/update/{id}', ['as' => 'equipment.update' , 'uses' => 'EquipmentController@update']);
Route::any('equipment/destroy/{id}', ['as' => 'equipment.destroy' , 'uses' => 'EquipmentController@destroy']);
Route::any('equipment/loadManufacturer', ['as'=>'equipment.loadManufacturer','uses'=>'EquipmentController@loadManufacturer']);
Route::any('equipment/loadMachine', ['as'=>'equipment.loadMachine','uses'=>'EquipmentController@loadMachine']);
Route::any('equipment/loadModel', ['as'=>'equipment.loadModel','uses'=>'EquipmentController@loadModel']);
Route::any('equipment/loadImage', ['as'=>'equipment.loadImage','uses'=>'EquipmentController@loadImage']);
 });
```

Comment: Which route are you trying to get to?

Comment: If you're on 5.2.27 or higher,  remove web middleware.

Answer (score 0):

The home route is commented man i think thats the issue here

```
//Route::any('/', function () { return view('user.dashboard'); });
```

Try to go to another route like

```
website.dev/user/login
```

Comment: no, when i uncomment that home route, i still cant hit the other urls. The login works fine and the dashboard works fine but sos, order and equipment doesnt work